# Qual a melhor maneira de salvar link de múltiplas imagens em um banco de dados?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, banco-de-dados, sql-server, modelagem

```
List<String> _lista = new List<String>();
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(Veiculo veiculo, HttpPostedFileBase[] file)
    {

            for (int i = 0; i < file.Length; i++)
            {
                var fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() +
                 System.IO.Path.GetExtension(file[i].FileName);
                file[i].SaveAs(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/Fotos/")
                                                  + fileName);
                _lista.Add(fileName);
            }
            veiculo.Imagem1 = _lista[0];
            veiculo.Imagem2 = _lista[1];
            veiculo.Imagem3 = _lista[2];
            veiculo.Imagem4 = _lista[3];
            veiculo.Imagem5 = _lista[4];
            db.Veiculo.Add(veiculo);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");

    }
```

O que preciso é que o usuário possa fazer o upload de quantas imagens ele quiser e não apenas 5 como e feito nesse meu código.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O ideal neste caso, segundo a normalização de dados, é separar essa informação em outra tabela em um relacionamento 1xN.

Por exemplo, criar a tabela `veiculo_imagens` com os campos `id_veiculo_imagens` (chave primária), `id_veiculo` (chave estrangeira) e `imagem`.

Com isso, 1 veículo poderá ter *n* imagens.